# Editable text in Illustrator

Tags: qgis, layers, editing, illustrator, maperitive

I'm new to QGIS and Maperitive. I wondered if there was a way to export all road /street names for a particular area as editable text in Illustrator (SVG)?

I have tried using Maperitive but for some reason when I export to SVG most of the words that I can see when zoomed in in Maperitive are either lost or missing letters.

Is there perhaps a mrules I could use that doesnt lose all the words?

Maybe there is a way to do this is QGIS with a particular plugin or layer?

Comment: QGIS 3.10.x exports PDF from the map composer which contain text as vector data.

Comment: Besides exporting to a PDF you can also export your map to an SVG, which also contains the text as vector data.

Comment: As per the [tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: Thank you all! I have tried to export as vector layer using map composer however it is still rasterised. Is there particular plugin / layer I should be downloading to create vectorised and editable text? Thanks again

Comment: By doing a bit of research I discovered that by double clicking the road layer (from OS Open Map - Local https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html) I can access labels. Here I could change the font and size

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by checking 'Export text as objects' while exporting to an SVG.

Comment: However this may bring other problems. This seemed to be my solution, but for some it includes parts of image outside map composer when exporting as SVG.